# How to plot a 4D function?

Tags: plotting

I am quite new to Mathematica. I have the following function:
f=(m1*m2+e1*e2)/(m1*m2+1);
where variables m1,m2,e1,e2 have the limitations: 1< m1< 5, 1< m2< 5, 0< e1< 1, 0< e2< 1.

Is there any way to plot f with all of these variables varying? I would like to see how f is changing continuously.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If linked topic does not fit your needs you need to be more precise about what exactly you would like to see, what project to what etc.

Comment: For your particular function, [`Plot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html) could be sufficient: Note that $f(m_1,m_2,e_1,e_2)=g(m_1m_2,e_1e_2)$ with $g(x,y)=(x+y)/(x+1)$. So essentially you only need to plot $g(x,y)$

Comment: Thank you very much Lukas, this would be a nice solution! However, I have 13 different functions like the first one that I want to plot and in many of them the variables are separated. Let me give another function:
h=e2(m1+e1)(m2+1)/((m1+1)(m2+e2))